# Can "inplore" be a valid word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been trying to find one word for searching within or searching inside self. So far I haven't found any.
It seems the prefix 'ex' in explore means 'out'. Then can I not say inplore to search inside?

Is there a better word that I haven't found yet?

Comment: 'Inplore' seems to be absent from respectable dictionaries. There may be a quirky nonce usage for a product say, modelled of course on 'explore'. But productiveness is gradable in English: just because something seems to follow a sensible pattern doesn't mean it's necessarily acceptable.  //// But research needs to be shown / mentioned, even if negative.

Comment: _Implore_ already exists, so _inplore_ likely never will. There are always compounds with _self-_, such as _self-exploration, self-examination, self-discovery,_ etc.

Comment: Thank you Edwin and Karl for your inputs. As you rightly pointed out inplore doesn't exist and I think using it will require more explanation rather than convey something in a word.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Ploro* in Latin means *to cry out*.  Originally, *explore* meant to hunt, to go around making duck-sounds or whatever, hoping to attract or startle some  animal so you could kill it and eat it.

As with a lot of stems beginning with `p` (“-plicit”, “-port”), the opposite of `ex-` is not `in-` but `im-`.  *Implore* means “to beg”, literally “to cry for help”, not to somehow hunt internally though.

Comment: I will now be unable to think of Columbus or Magellan without hearing "Quack."

Answer (score 3):

**Introspection** is the noun meaning 'searching within oneself'.

> *introspection* noun
>
> The examination or observation of one's own mental and emotional
>   processes.
>
> ‘quiet introspection can be extremely valuable’

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/introspection)]

The verb **introspect** also exists:

> *introspect* verb [ I ]
>
> ​ to examine and consider your own ideas, thoughts, and feelings

[[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/introspect)]

but is used far more rarely, as [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=introspection%2Cintrospect&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintrospection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintrospect%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest.

Comment: Of course introspection. I think I totally ignored it and started to look for another word to convey more active participation.  In my mind observation is more passive - you observe what is happening, while exploration is more active where you are taking action to find something rather than passively waiting for something to happen and observe.. Again, this is the meaning that I carry in my head, not sure if it makes sense to others...